# How to change a UIKit's property's default value globally?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Assuming this is possible, what's the best way to change the default value of a UIKit class's property?  For example, UIView's clipsToBounds has a default value of NO, but I would like to make it so all UIView in my app has clipsToBounds set to YES by default.

UPDATE:

Per Dave's suggestion, perhaps clipsToBounds is not the best example, but there will be properties or places where this is appropriate.

I would like to avoid having to create a subclass and changing all other classes accordingly if possible.  Perhaps the best way to do it is via UIView category and set the value in the +(void) load?

Answer (score 6):

You can create a subclass of `UIView` that sets that property in its constructor.

Comment: Subclassing is what I am trying to avoid.  Edited question.

Answer (score 1):

A word of warning:

You should only enable `clipsToBounds` on *your views*.  Enabling `clipsToBounds` on views provided by UIKit may have unintended consequences.  Some views are *designed* to extend their content beyond their bounds, and globally enabling clipping could have serious usability ramifications in your app.